# Rows between rownumber 1-2 million from an oracle table without field rownum in final output?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, rownum

How to get rows between row number 1 million to 2 million from an oracle table without having field rownum in final output?

Comment: `SELECT ... ORDER BY somecolumn OFFSET 100000 FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY`, for newer Oracle versions. (How much is a lak?)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
select col1, col2, col3, . . .
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum between 100000 and 200000;
```

That is, select the columns that you want in the output.

Comment: Thanks for answering....I know that this works but I wanted to know an alternative so that I don't have to write all the columns one by one (say 1000 colums).